# How would one draw samples from this X+Y where X ∼ N(5,2) and Y ∼ χ2(15) in r

Tags: r

X+Y where X ∼ N(5,2) and Y ∼ χ2(15)

I know u have to use norm() and chisq(). But i do not know how to put the two together. I am trying to draw 1000 samples. I am confused about X + Y

Answer (score 1):

Just add the two together

```
X = rnorm(1000, 5, 2)
Y = rchisq(1000, 2)
Z = X + Y
```

If you wanted to sample from `Z=X+Y` directly, then you had have to find the distribution of `Z`, which in this case is probably pretty difficult.

Check out `?rnorm` and `?rchisq` for more details.